# Want to stream just captured audio using VLC media player as HTTP or RTSP

Tags: raspbian, audio, vlc, streaming

When I try to use the [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player) GUI to start the stream, all the modes seem to include video, like v4l2. How do I tell it to only stream the audio card input?

The Raspberry Pi is next to my TV, and I want to be able to listen the TV audio using our Android and iPhone phones.

I want to use VLC media player because I have it on both my Android phone and PC, so I am familiar with it.

I am running on [Raspberry Pi B+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications) with [Raspbian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Software) using a cheap USB sound stick.

The [Advanced Linux Sound Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) (ALSA) utilities all seem to work.

Comment: what vlc command did you use?

Comment: I used the VLC GUI and selected mode: v4l2. I'm used to running it on Windows where DSHOW seems to be able to send only audio.  I have installed pulseaudio and am still trying to figure out how to get it to stream to the network.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to send audio from the TV to the Raspberry using a cable, then stream it from the Raspberry to your phone–wirelessly–over f.ex. http? Did any of the answers work for you? I have a Raspberry that streams to my Sonos speakers using Icecast software, not VCL, if that interests you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use v4l2 to capture sound through [PulseAudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PulseAudio).

First of all, find the correct device for pulseAudio. If you're using PulseAudio as a daemon, run this command at the command line:

```
pacmd list-sources | awk '/name:.+\.monitor/'
```

You should get output such as:

```
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor>
name: <alsa_output.usb-FORTEMEDIA_FM1083-00-FM1083.analog-mono.monitor>
name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor>
```

Then choose to output what you want from that list as the device for VLC media player:

```
cvlc pulse://alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [OMXPlayer](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/) which is shipped with the latest distibution of Raspbian.

Jack output:

```
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
sudo amixer cset numid=3 1
omxplayer -o hdmi [filename]
```

HDMI output (issue the first two lines if you used jack before - this is the default):

```
sudo modprobe snd_bcm2835
sudo amixer cset numid=3 0
omxplayer -o local [filename]
```

It uses the GPU to decode the audio files and supports a lot of various file types, like [MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3), [AAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding), [WAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV), etc. Unlike VLC media player which still hammers the CPU. So this is more efficient software to use and is easier.

Comment: Can OMXPlayer create an http audio stream? I'm not quite sure how this answer fits the question...